# How to connect scylladb into orm (typeOrm/knex or any other)

Tags: typeorm, knex.js, scylla

I wanna connect scylladb into any orm (seems there is no driver for scylla in typeorm)
is there any ways to use orm

Comment: typeorm drivers:
export type DatabaseType = "mysql" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sap" | "mariadb" | "sqlite" | "cordova" | "react-native" | "nativescript" | "sqljs" | "oracle" | "mssql" | "mongodb" | "aurora-mysql" | "aurora-postgres" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3" | "capacitor" | "spanner";